# Killing XP Zombies

Tags: windows-xp, process

Short of rebooting the machine, how does one kill zombies in XP?

I've tried TaskManager, ProcessExplorer, TaskKiller, ProcessHacker ... all of them fail.

Any suggestions?

Comment: load out 15 machine guns and wait for the zombies in your bunker. they'll come in hordes of 50 zombies, at 150 waves. make sure you bring enough bullets.

Comment: open up 25 notepad instances, then taskkill /f /im notepad.exe, this will get you a 25 kill streak, then nuke the zombies by pressing the left arrow key

Comment: Can we please clarify what a "zombie" is? In PC terms, not the walking dead...

Comment: GOOMHR [where R represents "dwa" :)] I was killing a few Vista zombies (which are big and heavy) just yesterday! Java zombies are even bigger and slower, so make sure you avoid them.

Comment: For those wondering a zombie process is a process which isn't dead (still exists) but has no threads associated with it IIRC, which I possibly don't.

Comment: The best way to kill Java zombies is to make sure there is no garbage around. Java zombies eat garbage, not brains.

Answer (score 7):

You can't.

Those tools all use the TerminateProcess API for force killing the process.  There is no TerminateProcessaHarder API that could be used instead.  If there was, these tools would use it already.